# RESTSharp 102 & Async+WP7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, restsharp

The newer 102 version broke my requests :(

this doesnt work anymove ...

```
client.ExecuteAsync<Resource>(request, (response) => {
    var resource = response.Data;
});
```

has anyone figured out how to use now? documentation is old :(

Comment: found the answer sorry ... client.ExecuteAsync<Resource>(request, (response) => {
    var resource = response.Data;
});

Comment: what error did you get? your solution looks like the same as the question. also are you on 102.1?

Answer (score 0):

The updated version as of 102.1 for wp7 looks like this.

```
// async with deserialization
var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Data.Name);
});
```

and yes it is now updated on the site
 coincidentally under the account of the same name as the guy in the comments.
 
@John Sheehan thanks for RestSharp
https://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp